# Multiple selection/combination filter with the jQuery isotope plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, filtering, jquery-isotope

I've searched and seen this has been questioned multiple times, however I've yet come to find one actual answer, which didn't help me out and a lot of unanswered ones. Well, let's hope this one will be answered with a suitable solution.

So, many developers know the great Isotope plugin. It includes a filter method, to filter items out of your container. However, it is possible to use multiple combinations at one ([check this](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/combination-filters.html)). Sadly, I'm not able to work it out.

I've coped the script from the page source and adapted it to my configuration (pointing to the correct div of your filters). But I'm stuck, and I don't know how to get it working.

Guys, check out this fiddle of the complete code.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dRCJ4/3/)

The actual script i'm using (also seen in the Fiddle).

```
    // filter buttons
$('#filters a').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  // don't proceed if already selected
  if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
    return;
  }

  var $optionSet = $this('.option-set');
  // change selected class
  $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $this.addClass('selected');

  // store filter value in object
  // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
  var group = $optionSet.attr('data-filter-group');
  filters[ group ] = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
  // convert object into array
  var isoFilters = [];
  for ( var prop in filters ) {
    isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
  }
  var selector = isoFilters.join('');
  $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

  return false;
});

});
```

*don't mind the data-flare tags, which are used for a different plugin*

Thanks!